# ransack rails: does not work with null values using *_in matchers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

i have requirement to search where i can select multiple drop-down (ex: status as "active", "")

I tried

```
User.ransack({status_in: ['active', ''])
```

and it returns result like

```
select * from users where status in ("active")
```

But expected result should be

```
select * from users where ("users"."deleted" != 't') AND status in ("active","")
```

how can i achieve this using ransack?(getting list of users where status is empty and'active')

Answer (score 3):

> how can i achieve this using ransack?(getting list of users where status is empty and'active')

I guess your goal is to get `users` with empty `or` active status. Then you probably need a separate [predicate](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#search-matchers) for this:

`*_blank` predicate checks, whether an attribute is null or empty using SQL: `col is null OR col = ''`.

And then [group the queries](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#grouping-queries-by-or-instead-of-and) using `OR`:

```
User.ransack(status_in: ['active'], status_blank: true, m: 'or')
```

It generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."status" IN ('active') OR ("users"."status" IS NULL OR "users"."status" = ''))
```

If you need to add one more condition, what about chaining it like a `Rails` query, since `ransack` just generates `ActiveRecord::Relation`:

```
User.ransack(deleted_not_eq: 't').result
  .ransack(status_in: ['active'], status_blank: true, m: 'or')
```

Comment: I can use OR condition but there is one more condition that has to AND  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."deleted" != 't') AND ("users"."status" IN ('active') OR ("users"."status" IS NULL OR "users"."status" = ''))

Comment: @Sidduh cool, then feel free to accept the answer (tick near the upvote section of the answer), if you think that the question is answered and completed

Comment: I'm Using ransack search_form_for for search form ex:                                    = search_form_for @q, class: 'search-form' do |f|                                             = f.input :status_in, as: :multiselect, collection: User.all                                    = f.input :deleted_not_eq when i use above suggested approach it works fine but value in the deleted input field getting erased.. any thing im doing wrong here